# How can I successfully cover these lines in my Apex class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

My test:

```
    @isTest
    private class CampaignRelatedListExtensionTest{
    static testMethod void validateCampaignRelatedListExtension()

        Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test Account', Type = 'Prospect', BillingCountry = 'United States', BillingState = 'Alabama');
        insert acc;

        Account acc2 = new Account(Name = 'Testing Account', Type = 'Prospect', BillingCountry = 'United States', BillingState = 'Alabama');
        insert acc2;

        Account acc3 = new Account(Name = 'Tested Account', Type = 'Prospect', BillingCountry = 'United States', BillingState = 'Alabama');
        insert acc3;

        Account acc4 = new Account(Name = 'Testeded Account', Type = 'Prospect', BillingCountry = 'United States', BillingState = 'Alabama');
        insert acc4;

        Account acc5 = new Account(Name = 'Testorous Account', Type = 'Prospect', BillingCountry = 'United States', BillingState = 'Alabama');
        insert acc5;

        Account acc6 = new Account(Name = 'Testoid Account', Type = 'Prospect', BillingCountry = 'United States', BillingState = 'Alabama');        
        insert acc6;

        Contact c = new Contact(AccountID = acc.Id, LastName = 'TestContact', Email = 'test.contact@testing.com');
        insert c;

        Contact c2 = new Contact(AccountID = acc2.Id, LastName = 'TestingContact', Email = 'testing.contact@testing.com');
        insert c2;

        Contact c3 = new Contact(AccountID = acc3.Id, LastName = 'TestedContact', Email = 'tested.contact@testing.com');
        insert c3;

        Contact c4 = new Contact(AccountID = acc4.Id, LastName = 'TestededContact', Email = 'testeded.contact@testing.com');
        insert c4;

        Contact c5 = new Contact(AccountID = acc5.Id, LastName = 'TestoidContact', Email = 'testoid.contact@testing.com');
        insert c5;

        Contact c6 = new Contact(AccountID = acc6.Id, LastName = 'TestorousContact',  Email = 'testorous.contact@testing.com');
        insert c6;

        Campaign cam = new Campaign(Name = 'Test Campaign', Month__c = 'November', Year__c = '2016');
        insert cam;

        Campaign cam2 = new Campaign(Name = 'Testing Campaign', Month__c = 'November', Year__c = '2016');
        insert cam2;

        Campaign cam3 = new Campaign(Name = 'Tested Campaign', Month__c = 'November', Year__c = '2016');
        insert cam3;

        Campaign cam4 = new Campaign(Name = 'Testeded Campaign', Month__c = 'November', Year__c = '2016');
        insert cam4;

        Campaign cam5 = new Campaign(Name = 'Testoid Campaign', Month__c = 'November', Year__c = '2016');
        insert cam5;

        Campaign cam6 = new Campaign(Name = 'Testorous Campaign', Month__c = 'November', Year__c = '2016');
        insert cam6;

        CampaignMember cm = new CampaignMember(CampaignId = cam.Id, ContactId = c.Id, Description__c = 'Note');
        insert cm;

        CampaignMember cm2 = new CampaignMember(CampaignId = cam2.Id, ContactId = c2.Id, Description__c = 'Note2');
        insert cm2;

        CampaignMember cm3 = new CampaignMember(CampaignId = cam3.Id, ContactId = c3.Id, Description__c = 'Note3');
        insert cm3;

        CampaignMember cm4 = new CampaignMember(CampaignId = cam4.Id, ContactId = c4.Id, Description__c = 'Note4');
        insert cm4;

        CampaignMember cm5 = new CampaignMember(CampaignId = cam5.Id, ContactId = c5.Id, Description__c = 'Note5');
        insert cm5;

        CampaignMember cm6 = new CampaignMember(CampaignId = cam6.Id, ContactId = c6.Id, Description__c = 'Note6');
        insert cm6;


        Test.startTest();






        ApexPages.StandardController stdCon = new ApexPages.StandardController(cm);
        ManageListController mlc = new ManageListController(stdCon);
        mlc.addRows();
        mlc.save(); 



        system.assert(Cam.Name == 'Test Campaign');
        system.assert(Cam2.Name == 'Testing Campaign');
        system.assert(Cam3.Name == 'Tested Campaign');
        system.assert(Cam4.Name == 'Testeded Campaign');
        system.assert(Cam5.Name == 'Testoid Campaign');
        system.assert(Cam6.Name == 'Testorous Campaign');
        system.assert(C.LastName == 'TestContact');
        system.assert(C2.LastName == 'TestingContact');
        system.assert(C3.LastName == 'TestedContact');
        system.assert(C4.LastName == 'TestededContact');
        system.assert(C5.LastName == 'TestoidContact');
        system.assert(C6.LastName == 'TestorousContact');
        system.assert(acc.Name == 'Test Account');
        system.assert(acc2.Name == 'Testing Account');
        system.assert(acc3.Name == 'Tested Account');
        system.assert(acc4.Name == 'Testeded Account');
        system.assert(acc5.Name == 'Testorous Account');
        system.assert(acc6.Name == 'Testoid Account');
        system.assert(Cm.Description__c == 'Note');
        system.assert(Cm2.Description__c == 'Note2');
        system.assert(Cm3.Description__c == 'Note3');
        system.assert(Cm4.Description__c == 'Note4');
        system.assert(Cm5.Description__c == 'Note5');
        system.assert(Cm6.Description__c == 'Note6');


        Test.stopTest();
}             
}
```

My class:

```
public with sharing class ManageListController {
 public List<CMWrapper> wrappers {get; set;}
 public List<CampaignMember> campaignMembers { get; private set; }
 public static Integer addCount {get;set;}
 private Integer nextIdent=0; 
  public ManageListController()
 {
    wrappers=new List<CMWrapper>();
    for (Integer idx=0; idx<5; idx++)
    {
     wrappers.add(new CMWrapper(nextIdent++));
    }
 }
 public void addRows()
 {
  for (Integer idx=0; idx<addCount;idx++)
  {
   wrappers.add(new CMWrapper(nextIdent++));  
  }
 }
 public PageReference save()
 {
  update CampaignMembers;
    return null;
 }                           
 public class CMWrapper
 {
  public campaignmember cm {get;private set;} 
    public Integer ident {get;private set;}

    public CMWrapper(Integer inIdent)
    {
     ident=inIdent;
     cm=new CampaignMember(Notes__c ='Note ' + ident);
    }    
   }
 public ManageListController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        campaignMembers = [
            SELECT Campaign.Name, Campaign.Startdate, Campaign.Type, Notes__c, Created_By__c FROM CampaignMember
            WHERE ContactId = :controller.getId()

        ];  
  }
   }
```

I´m at 73% overall, but the coverage for this class with this test is currently at 45%. The lines that I´m unsure how to cover:

```
     public List<CMWrapper> wrappers {get; set;}

public ManageListController()

{
    wrappers=new List<CMWrapper>();
    for (Integer idx=0; idx<5; idx++)
    {
     wrappers.add(new CMWrapper(nextIdent++));
    }
 }

{
  public campaignmember cm {get;private set;} 
    public Integer ident {get;private set;}

    public CMWrapper(Integer inIdent)
    {
     ident=inIdent;
     cm=new CampaignMember(Notes__c ='Note ' + ident);
    }
```

Edit: Thanks for the answers! My test now runs successfully. I´ll post an answer showing my completed test class if I manage to reach 75% coverage today (still 2% short). I´m still working on some of the suggestions posted below, but further suggestions are still welcome.

Answer (score 1):

```
public ManageListController()
 {
    wrappers=new List<CMWrapper>();
    for (Integer idx=0; idx<5; idx++)
    {
     wrappers.add(new CMWrapper(nextIdent++));
    }
 }

{
   if (wrappers[idx].ident==toDelIdent)
   {
    toDelPos=idx;   
   }
  }
   if(-1!=toDelPos)  
   {
    wrappers.remove(toDelPos);   
   }
 }
```

You'll notice the above code references and `idx<5`. That means you need multiple records to be able to test this code. You need to be creating multiple accounts and related contacts for what you want to do. It's also preferable to test one feature at a time using separate test methods rather than one "God Method".

Further, I recommend you use a RunAs User who has the requisite permissions to for accessing Campaigns (Marketing User Permissions or the profile of the user who this page is intended for). You can use a separate RunAs user to create the Accounts.

You also should be using `Test.StartTest()` and `Test.StopTest()` with the former beginning after you've finished inserting your data and the latter when you've finished manipulating it.

I notice that the dates for your `campaigns` are very old. I'd recommend you change that to use the Year of Today().

That said, what I think is particularly causing your issue with the `nullpointerexception` is that your contacts aren't inserting. All `contacts` require an `email` address. Yours don't have one. Giving them one should likely make your code work.

See the [Apex Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing.htm) for more on how you should be creating your test classes along with the Trailhead module for Apex Test Classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can take an approach like this:

Assign the value for `toDelIdent`.

```
ManageListController mc = new ManageListController(stdCon);
mc.toDelIdent = 1; //for example
mc.delWrapper();
```

Before executing perform the delete operation verify the size of the `wrappers`.

If the `size` is 0 then add entries to this add and try to perform delete.

Basically, delete operation is getting performed from your visualforce. So you need to replicate same scenario in your test method.

Hope it helps.